# How to keep SplashImage always ON?

Tags: autohotkey

I have following code using AutoHotKey, it will display image on screen on particular X & Y Coordinate.

But it will only stay on for 5 Second or however many I enter.

Is there a way for it not Splash off?

```
SplashImage, On
SplashImage, C:\Users\unknown\Desktop\9xm.jpg, b X250 Y250 fs30, 35
Sleep, 5000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The splash image should (will) stay on UNTIL it it is turned `Off` by a (can be another) script OR, *and I think this might be the case in your situation*, when the script is closed with e.g. `ExitApp`.

When I run the following code by pressing <kbd>F8</kbd>, the image stays on top of the screen UNTIL I restart AutoHotKey (or close it through `SplashImage, Off`).

```
F8::
    SplashImage, C:\Users\Robert\Downloads\dialect.jpg
Return
```

Oh b.t.w. Even with your arguments, this image still stays on top until I restart AutoHotKey.

Comment: If so, why this script only flashs in this script containing only these 2 lines: `Splashimage, ,M2 cwolive, test`
`return` ?